# Cocoa OS X application top menu loses control

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow

I have strange situation where my OS X application top menu no longer works and loses all control to the application. For example Command + Quit does not work, file menu does not work etc.

It does not happens always and mostly happens when system goes to sleep for long time or system restarted unexpectedly or app is running for long time like 2-3 days.

I have tried a lot to figure it out but no luck so far so may be i can find help here.

Regards,
MP.

Comment: Seems like no one has any clue about it?

Comment: Can anyone please give me a clue what's wrong with app?